# How to Redirect URL with special Characters?

Tags: htaccess, redirects

I try to redirect a special URL in .htaccess, as below:

```
Redirect 301 /aor/%e2%80%9d https://www.example.com/outlook-repair/
```

But this seems does not work. I try to add quotes, as follows:

```
Redirect 301 "/aor/%e2%80%9d" https://www.example.com/outlook-repair/
```

But also not work. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Because the `Redirect` directive matches against the %-decoded URL-path. `%e2%80%9d` is a URL-encoded "closing curly quote" (U+201D: RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK).

For example

```
Redirect 301 "/aor/”" https://www.example.com/outlook-repair/
```

You need to ensure your `.htaccess` file is saved with a UTF-8 encoding.

Reference:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

---

To specifically match against the %-encoded URL-path (or rather, the URL as requested by the client) then you would need to use mod_rewrite and check against `THE_REQUEST` server variable.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,7}\s/aor/%e2%80%9d\sHTTP
RewriteRule ^aor/ https://www.example.com/outlook-repair/ [R=301,L]
```

`THE_REQUEST` server variable contains the first line of the HTTP request headers as sent from the client. eg. A string of the form:

```
GET /aor/%e2%80%9d HTTP/1.1
```